# Como chamar uma função server side no evento onclick NextJS

Tags: onclick, next.js

Estou montando uma loja virtual e NextJs.

Onde na listagem dos produtos há o botão "ADICIONAR AO CARRINHO".

A ideia é que ao clicar nesse botão (client side) seja salvo no banco o item adicionado sem sair da pagina em que está.

A ideia é mais ou menos essa:

```
"use client";

import addProdutoCarrinho from "@/lib/store/addProdutoCarrinho";

export default function ButtonCart() {

function addCart(){
  
  addProdutoCarrinho();

}

  return (
    <button
      onClick={addCart}
      className="bg-brand text-white p-2 mt-3 uppercase"
    >
      Adicionar Carrinho
    </button>
  );
}
```

Onde `addProdutoCarrinho()` já faz o cadastro corretamente.

O problema é que é server side, ou seja, não executa no onClick dando erro.

Comment: Use AJAX, e faça uma requisição para API. Veja https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Answer (score -2):

Utilizando o padrão do NextJs 13, você pode utilizar Hooks (useEffect) para executar um fetch (POST) onde ficará o backend dessa interação.